# Azure portal: How to find today's visitors count of my Azure web app?

Tags: azure

I have an ASP.NET Core web app on Azure. I'm using Azure Portal, of course. It is running fine, no problems.

Here is my question:  Where in the Portal can I find out how many visitors the website has had today?

I've looked into Application Insights, but it looks like a large amount of study and work just to answer a simple, ordinary question: How many visitors today?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a metric available for Azure App Services, closest you can get is the number of requests. You can look at the metrics if you open the metrics blade of the App Service

Answer (score 4):

I see you mentioned application insights. And for your case, it's the easy and convenient way, just a few steps.

1.Create an application insights:

[image]

2.In azure portal, nav to your web app -> in the left blade, select "Application Insights", and click "Turn on site extension" -> fill in necessary fields -> click Apply button:

[image]

3.Now everything is ready, if you want to see how many users visit your site, just nav to the application insights -> in the left blade, click Users:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately in your step 3, when I click Usage/Users, the Portal tells me I need to take further steps: a. Add the Application Insights JavaScript SDK snippets to each page I want to track. b. Add a custom event, c. Re-deploy and refresh this page.

Comment: Ivan I'm grateful to you for your help. I decided against adding the Application Insights kit to my Visual Studio project, just to avoid extra complexity.  Also I want to avoid any increases to my bill at Azure. Thank you.